# What is the Karmic Effect of Harsh Speech?

Tags: karma, right-speech, sila

What are the karmic fruits/consequences of speaking harshly to others?

Answer (score 7):

The mind & body is disturbed, with agitation & stress ('*hell*').

Friends may be lost or social status (such as a job) may be lost, which results in deficiency & need ('*hungry ghost*').

Shame & regret will eventually arise internally  (if the mind returns to a normal or '*human*' state).

> *Pharusā, bhikkhave, vācā āsevitā bhāvitā bahulīkatā niraya­saṃ­vatta­nikā tiracchā­na­yoni­saṃ­vatta­nikā
>   petti­visa­ya­saṃ­vatta­nikā. Yo sabbalahuso pharusāya vācāya vipāko,
>   ­manus­sa­bhūtassa amanā­pa­saddasaṃ­vatta­niko hoti*
>
> *Harsh speech — when indulged in, developed & pursued — is something that leads to (saṃvattanika) hell (niraya), leads to the animal birth (tiracchā­na­yoni), leads to the
>   realm (­visa­ya) of the hungry shades (petti­). The slightest of all the results coming
>   from harsh speech is that, when one becomes human (manus­sa), it leads to
>   unappealing (amanā­pa­) sounds.*
>
> [*AN 8.40 Vipaka Sutta*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.040.than.html)

Answer (score 1):

> "There is the case, where a woman or man is ill-tempered & easily upset; even when lightly criticized, he/she grows offended, provoked, malicious, & resentful; shows annoyance, aversion, & bitterness. Through having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the body, after death, he/she reappears in the plane of deprivation, the bad destination, the lower realms, hell. If, on the break-up of the body, after death — instead of reappearing in the plane of deprivation, the bad destination, the lower realms, hell. If instead he/she comes to the human state, then he/she is ugly wherever reborn. This is the way leading to ugliness: to be ill-tempered & easily upset; even when lightly criticized, to grow offended, provoked, malicious, & resentful; to show annoyance, aversion, & bitterness.
>
> "But then there is the case where a woman or man is not ill-tempered or easily upset; even when heavily criticized, he/she doesn't grow offended, provoked, malicious, or resentful; doesn't show annoyance, aversion, or bitterness. Through having adopted & carried out such actions, on the break-up of the body, after death, he/she reappears in a good destination... If instead he/she comes to the human state, then he/she is beautiful wherever reborn. This is the way leading to beauty: not to be ill-tempered or easily upset; even when heavily criticized, not to be offended, provoked, malicious, or resentful; nor to show annoyance, aversion, & bitterness.
>
> [Cula-kammavibhanga Sutta: The Shorter Analysis of Action](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than_en.html)
> *(this is a gift of Dhamma, it's not given to be sold or for any wordly gains. [d-gift](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.than_en.html#F_termsOfUse))*